# APScheduler callback function - how can I call some funtion/module in python when a job is completed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, callback, apscheduler

Hi I am using APScheduler in a Django project. How can I plan a call of a function in python when the job is done? A callback function.

I store job as Django models in DB. As it completes, I want to mark it as `completed=1` in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and generic way to do it would be to add your callback function to the end of the scheduled job. You can also build on top of the scheduler class to include a self.function_callback() at the end of the tasks.

Quick example:

```
def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())
    time.sleep(10)
    function_cb()

def function_cb():
    print "CallBack Function"
    #Do Something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=2)
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
    # Execution will block here until Ctrl+C (Ctrl+Break on Windows) is pressed.
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
        scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Comment: Yes I agree. I have asked the author in the gitter channel, and found that this is not possible with APScheduler. What you say is legit, but my use case is different, because the process to launch takes some time, so I cannot be sure to mark it as complete when the scheduler launches the job. The only thing I can figure out is to add another job independent to mark the complete state, but (1) it cannot guarantee nothing, (2) it is ugly: two jobs for one thing. So at last I gave up on this, just don't mark it. Thanks, marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[Listener](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#scheduler-events) allows to hook various [events](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/events.html#event-codes) of APScheduler. I have succeeded to get the *next run time* of my job using EVENT_JOB_SUBMITTED.

(Updated)
I confirmed whether it is able to hook these events.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, Filter, basicConfig, INFO

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED, EVENT_JOB_ERROR


logger = getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(INFO)


def tick():
    now = datetime.now()
    logger.info('Tick! The time is: %s' % now)
    if now.second % 2 == 0:
        raise Exception('now.second % 2 == 0')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sh = StreamHandler()
    sh.addFilter(Filter('__main__'))
    basicConfig(
            handlers = [sh],
            format='[%(asctime)s] %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )

    def my_listener(event):
        if event.exception:
            logger.info('The job crashed')
        else:
            logger.info('The job worked')

    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.add_listener(my_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

When this code is executed, the output is as follows:

```
Interrupt: Press ENTER or type command to continue
Press Ctrl+C to exit
[2019-11-30 09:24:12] __main__ INFO: Tick! The time is: 2019-11-30 09:24:12.663142
[2019-11-30 09:24:12] __main__ INFO: The job crashed
[2019-11-30 09:24:15] __main__ INFO: Tick! The time is: 2019-11-30 09:24:15.665845
[2019-11-30 09:24:15] __main__ INFO: The job worked
[2019-11-30 09:24:18] __main__ INFO: Tick! The time is: 2019-11-30 09:24:18.663215
[2019-11-30 09:24:18] __main__ INFO: The job crashed
```

Comment: Yes, you know when it is submitted to the scheduler, but you don't have a hook of job completion; once the job is launched, you have no callback to know if it is done; it is out of scope, as I think of it now.

Comment: EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED presents 'A job was executed successfully'. EVENT_JOB_ERROR presents 'A job raised an exception during execution'. Is it possible with these?